# can we implement HTTP Digest Proxy over SSL on iPhone programmatically, is it possible?

Tags: ios, authentication, ssl, http-proxy, digest

I am trying to implement Http Digest Authentication over SSL for one of my clients. I could not find any reference related to this. Is this possible to implement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several research, I found out that, iOS does not provide any such in built support for Http authentication over SSL, expect SOCKS. But if you are desperate to implement it, create a socket and do Digest/NTLM/... handshake your self and use the same socket to create Input/Output streams. As of now, this is the only way to do it.

However, for regular Http requests such as POST/GET/... you can use NSURLConnection class as following code to authenticate the servers.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"InShiva didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge") ;
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"
                                                                password:@"password"
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        NSLog(@"credential created");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
    }
}
```